# how to stop setState wrapping the changes in a new object

Tags: reactjs, setstate

Initially look at the console at the cars object which is an object of objects. But after the setState call it is wrapped into a new object for which my latter display code is not working. How to stop this wrapping, rather i want to just modify the existing object.

The lines from 18-22

[look at the console here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKirH.png)

Comment: Please [do not post code as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

`setState()` is not wrapping anything. The issue with your code is that you're passing a wrapper object as a parameter to `setState()`:

```
setCars({
   cars: allCars
});
```

And that's exactly what you get in your state: an object with a single property `cars`. If you want the state to mantain the previous shape, just pass a properly shaped object:

```
setCars({...allCars});
```